# Oscillating Euler DE and its solution

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Consider the DE $$y''+\frac{k}{x^2}y=0 \quad \Bbb{for} \quad x>0$$
Despite the fact that $$\int_1^{\infty}dx\;x^{-2}$$ exists, the solutions of this DE may oscillate.

a) Show that they do if k>1/4 and dont if k≤1/4.

b) Show that the solutions of $$y'' + \frac{1}{1+x^2}y = 0 $$ do oscillate by referring to the result of a).

By my understanding, the question is asking me to solve the Euler DE given and obtain the k value as 1/4. But how would I know that the last equation oscillates just from the results of a)? Would it be just because the overall function is the same?

Comment: Do you mean:  $\int_1^{\infty} {1\over x^2} dx $ exists?

Comment: yes I did. Thank you for pointing it out!

Answer (score 1):

a) Find, as usual for an Euler-Cauchy DE, basis solutions in the form $y(x)=x^r$ with characteristic equation $$0=r(r-1)+k=(r-\tfrac12)^2+k-\tfrac14.$$ In the case of non-real $r$, combine the conjugate solutions into a real basis $\sqrt{x}\cos(\omega\ln x),\sqrt{x}\sin(\omega\ln x)$.

b) Apply the Sturm-Picone comparison theorem, you could even use it twice to get upper and lower bounds from $$\frac1{(x+1)^2}\le \frac1{1+x^2}\le\frac1{x^2}.$$

This means that between any two roots of $\cos(ω\ln(x+1))$ you find at least one root of $y(x)$, and between any two roots of $y(x)$ you find a root of $\cos(ω\ln(x))$. Or more adapted, if $y(a)=0$, then $y$ as another root $b$ before the next root of $\sin(ω(\ln(x+1)-\ln(a+1)))$ and after the root of $\sin(ω(\ln x-\ln a))$, $$ae^{\pi/ω}\le b\le (a+1)e^{\pi/ω}-1.$$ As this gives finite distances between roots, there has to be an infinite number of roots.